# Add string "error completing request; try again later" from analytics page into transifex

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/analytics

> [image]

String:

> error completing request; try again later

Could you add this string into transifex, so we will be able to translate it?